Lubuntu freezes on the blue loading screen whit this error: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0f.0:corb reset timeout#1 corbrp = 0
edit: I tried again and there is new error
I'm trying to resurrect an old laptop with Lubuntu installation but when I select "install Lubuntu" it freezes on the blue screen and also has a strange effect (as if the screen were burning) which however can be resolved using the "safe graphics" option, but with this, the following error shows up:

corb reset timeout#1 corbrp = 0

The same thing happens to me with Ubuntu.
The laptop has a Pentium T3400 (that overheats to 70°C) and an ATI RADEON HD 4570 512MB.

If it over heats at such a low temp I suggest this computer is not much good for anything. You might try opening and cleaning it otherwise not going to work.

I think the problem is the network card cuz i tried with kali and the installer freezed at  "detecting network card". After removing it the installer works well.
(yes i cleaned the fan, I think it needs a new termal paste)
